# Applet access JDialog information

Tags: java, javascript, swing, applet, awt

I'm trying to obtain information in a `JDialog` that is opened by an applet. This applet is not developed by me and I don't have the source code.

I can access this applet by JavaScript using the following:

```
 var aApp = document.applets[0];
 var acApplet = aApp.getAccessibleContext();
```

I can access all controls inside the main applet, but when the applet trigger a dialog, I can't access the objects inside this dialog. I tried to find Components inside the applet and inside the `JFrame` that is the parent of this applet.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate [`Window.getWindows()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#getWindows--).  The dialog should be one of them.